# How to calculate test coverage while using Robolectric

Tags: android, makefile, code-coverage, robolectric

I am using `make` for building and `Robolectric` as a framework for running Android tests. I would like to calculate coverage of my app. For instrumentation tests I used to use `emmalib`. What is the best way for me to set up coverage calculation in this case? I can't migrate to gradle or maven.

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466482/generating-android-code-coverage-though-changes-in-build-xml-and-ant-properties

Comment: How about using RoboElectric + Cobertura/EclEmma for code coverage?

Comment: Slartibartfast: We don't use ant. Do you have some tutorial on how to integrate Robo and Cobertura/EclEmma? I will be trying to use JaCoCo today.

Comment: Well most of the tutorials I have come across use ant unfortunately, and I dont think it would be a bad idea for you to use ant. But JaCoCo you could take a look at here: https://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/code-coverage-of-robolectric-tests-using-jacoco/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you bound to Emma?  How about using RoboElectric + [Cobertura](https://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) code coverage?  (I think you could just use a CLI for the above combination)

So options

1.) RoboElectric + Cobertura - CLI alone probably for someone not on ANT

2.) JaCoCo might have some useful options

3.) Pure Android Testing + Emma/EclEmma

**Useful Link trails to follow**

[Generating android code coverage though changes in build.xml and ant.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13466482/1081340)

[Android Gradle Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17100830/1081340)

https://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/code-coverage-of-robolectric-tests-using-jacoco/

https://bitbucket.org/ravidsrk/androidstarter

**EDIT:**

Well most of the tutorials I have come across use ant unfortunately, and I don't think it would be a bad idea for you to move to a recommended build system like Gradle so it opens up a lot options. But for JaCoCo you could take a look at here: https://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/code-coverage-of-robolectric-tests-using-jacoco/

**UPDATE:**

Moved this from comments to the answer section for information to anyone wanting to see this and because this is a bounty question

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use [Cobertura](https://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) to generate code coverage, which can be integrated in eclipse and also run by an ant build script.

A template project of such an integration can be found here: https://github.com/adgllorente/android-cobertura-boilerplate

Note that all of the magic happens in the [build.xml](https://github.com/adgllorente/android-cobertura-boilerplate/blob/develop/HelloWorldTest/build.xml) of the Test project. Theses tasks should probably be generalised to a `custom_rules.xml` file so you can still use `android` to update your projects.

Finally, for Gradle you have many different options:

- http://raptordigital.blogspot.nl/2014/08/code-coverage-reports-using-robolectric.html
- http://chrisjenx.com/gradle-robolectric-jacoco-dagger/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037742/2771851

Note that you can always use Gradle as a secondary build system just to generate the coverage reports. (but a second build system will introduce a lot of overhead)

Comment: I don't use gradle, or maven, or ant. My build is purely Make based (check out AOSP code base). I will take a look at cobertura, which seems to allow working from cmd line without anything else.

Answer (score 1):

jacoco sometimes does not work with Robelectric and powermock runner you can use clover an atlassian tools it is now open source tool.